# select records between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table something like this..

```
TeacherName         | Class | Section  | SubjectId |    Date   | ToDate    |Day
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Matt         |   12  | B        | Math      |2013-03-04 |2013-03-14 |Mon
       John         |   12  | A        | Phy       |2013-04-03 |2013-04-12 |Mon
```

I want a query something like this(not actual sql query)...

```
Select * 
from Table 
where Class='12' and section='B' and Date= '2013-03-07'
```

This should give me the first row which has `Matt` because given date `2013-03-07` lies within that row's date range from `2013-03-04` to `2013-03-14`.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Have you actually tried it?

Comment: i used between keyword but that wont work in this case.

Comment: Select * from Table where Class='12' and section='B' and Date= '2013-03-07' 
 does not return anything

Comment: @MahmoudGamal because i was using it the wrong way JW. answered it. THanks anyways Mahmoud :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `BETWEEN`

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    TableName
WHERE   Class = '12' AND 
        Section = 'B' AND 
        '2013-03-07' BETWEEN DATE AND TODATE
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c3472/1)

Comment: This is the fastest answer i have got so far on this site. lol
Where do you guys learn so much stuff??

Comment: And this is "inclusive", correct?  Meaning if the TODATE is 12-31-2014 all records on that date are included